# Convert list of numbers to percent between positive and negative number

Tags: math, statistics

I have a list of numbers like -17, -50, 100, 120, 5, 20 Now how to convert this series to percent. I have a problem in negative number in converting to percent. For example i want to convert these number between 0 to 1 or 0% to 100%

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of arithmetic not one of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase all number with minimum and convert it to percent.

```
-17+abs(-50) = 33
-50+abs(-50) = 0
100+abs(-50) = 150
120+abs(-50) = 170
5+abs(-50) = 55
20+abs(-50) = 70
After all result should convert like an this:
(number / max) * 100
(55 / 170) * 100 = 32.35%
(70 / 170) * 100 = 41.17%
(170 / 170) * 100 = 100%
```

Comment: Isn't abs(-50) just 50? Since 'abs'  converts negatives to positives while leaving any that are already positive as they are.

Comment: The minimum number is -50, and with abs(-50) we show to remove negative from number.